# Are there any other irregular verbs in imperfect tense?

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto, formas-irregulares

Googling irregular verbs in Spanish for imperfect tense always ends up with a simple three verbs: `ir`, `ser`, `ver`.

Some pages even go as far as saying *"There are only 3 irregular verbs in imperfect"*.

Is this the ultimate truth, or are there more?

And if there is indeed more, what type of sources do you recommend me to consult as "authority" on these topics?

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to prove a negative, but it seems to be correct (excluding verbs derived from those three, such as *prever*, *entrever*).

Comment: Thank you and thanks for those derived ones as well. Would you maybe consider putting this into an answer so I could accept it and mark this as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que yo tenga noticias, en español casi todos los verbos en imperfecto son regulares
y solo existen tres verbos en el que el imperfecto es irregular.

[image]

Los demás hipotéticos casos derivan, se desarrollan o se conjugan teniendo como base estos y por tanto no pueden considerarse, en este sentido, totalmente autónomos o distintos, como verbos irregulares en el imperfecto.

Así "prever" no es más que una composición con componentes léxicos, procedentes del latín "praevidere", ver con antelación o anticipación, el prefijo "pre" (antes) y el verbo "videre" (**ver**).

El caso de "entrever" es otro tanto, esta compuesto del prefijo entre (acción reciproca) y nuevamente del verbo latino "videre" (**ver**). Ver una cosa confusamente algo, conjeturar, sospechar o adivinar algo.

Comment: Never realized until now that prever is also irregular imperfect. Very helpful, upvote.